Managing Power and Sleep in a BK 7600G from AND-technologies
I work with a BK-7600G board that has a SIMCOM7600G.Documentation of the manufacturer (AND-technologies) seems to me limited.
A. Regarding power on and power off:
Using the POWERKEY
We see in the circuit that the PWRKEY pin of the board is connected to GND by R104, a resistor whose value is not printed in the schematic.
Doc writes "shorted to ground". If the resistor is not 0R the term "shorted" seems wrong.
Unsolder R104 ??? to be able to polarize SIMCOM 7600G module as per Simcom documentation?
Other modules from Simcom, like the 7080, really uses this pin. The 7080 only starts when PWRPIN is GND for 2 seconds. But 7600 starts automatically without externally connect PWRPIN.
B. REGARDING PUT TO SLEEP AND AWAKE UNIT
The DTR line of the module is not exposed to a pin in the board.
The board implements a SLEEP pin that is connected to the base of a transistor. But documentation does not say what voltage to apply for each state (Sleep or Run)
We did not try to use PWRKEY nor SLEEP pins because we do not want to fry a 38 buck board. I try to learn before.
Thanks for your help, in case someone has used this same board.
Kind regards,
Horacio

We don't see anything in any circuit, I'm afraid. And a Google search for "BK-7600G" yields nothing

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you !
This is the module:
https://www.and-global.com/es/sim7600g-breakout-board-mini-sim7600g-h-cat4-kits-with-gps-4g-antenna.html
Objectives:

Be able to power on and power of via PWRPIN, "AS IS" the module is impossible.
Unless to unsolder a component (undocumented partially) and take the risk to fry the electronics.
Get advice from a user about the SLEEP pin, that also do not expose the DTR i need to access.

